# How to sort Dictionary by ascending?

Tags: c#

so I have this dictionary

```
Dictionary<ulong, PlayerData> PlayersCache = new Dictionary<ulong, PlayerData>();
```

I have class PlayerData

```
        public class PlayerData
        {
            public int Shots;
            public int Hits;
            public PlayerData()
            {
            }
        }
```

How can I sort Dictionary so player with the most hits will be first the second player with most hits will be second, third player with most hits will be third... In the Dictionary Sort it ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a value ID to the class:

```
public class PlayerData
{
    public ulong ID;
    public int Shots;
    public int Hits;
    public PlayerData()
    {
    }
}
```

The sorting:

```
Dictionary<ulong, PlayerData> PlayersCache = new Dictionary<ulong, PlayerData>();

// ... adding records to the dictionary

List<PlayerData> lst = new List<PlayerData>();
foreach (var kv in PlayersCache)
{
    lst.Add(kv.Value);
    kv.Value.ID = kv.Key;
}

lst.Sort(delegate (PlayerData x, PlayerData y) {
    return y.Hits.CompareTo(x.Hits);
});

PlayersCache.Clear();

foreach(var p in lst)
{
    PlayersCache.Add(p.ID, p);
}
```

Comment: and I read it normally from PlayersCache?
 foreach (var aPlayer in BasePlayer.activePlayerList)
            {
                if (PlayersCache.ContainsKey(aPlayer.userID))
                {

Comment: This part: `foreach (var aPlayer in BasePlayer.activePlayerList) { if (PlayersCache.ContainsKey(aPlayer.userID)) }` is not located in your code in your question. When do you execute this code?

Comment: I execute it to create UI Panel for each player etc... It is in UnityEngine

Comment: It looks like that is not related to your question. Do you execute that before or after the sorting?

Comment: I execute it every 2 seconds Look https://imgur.com/qVyyaOu.png

Comment: Anyway, your question is about sorting a dictionary and solution provided. If you just want to sort the list, then you don't actually need dictionary. You can sort the list without the dictionary.

Comment: First guy is always the one added first in PlayersCache I wanted to change the order in foreach

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
var ordered = PlayersCache.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Value.Hits);
```

You can add .ToList() or similar to end depending on how you wish to use it.

Comment: `_` as a semi-discard is ok, but not as useable variable later please.

Comment: @Sinatr Your point is valid, but from the question I don't think it is particularly important.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unsorted (though that are implementations that sort by *key* value). If you want to sort by values then don't use a dictionary - use either a `List<Key, Value>` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289), or a sorted `Lookup` as provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942207)